# Grunt Sassdown handlebars not creating iframe

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js

I'm setting up a little Grunt.js using Sassdown to create a styleguide. I've got it on github here - https://github.com/sturobson/Squeeler

The specific code being use to create the Styleguide is -

```
sassdown: {
  options: {
    template_assets: 'source/styleguide/',
    template_html: 'source/styleguide.hbs',
    includes: 'source/site_includes.hbs'
  },
  files: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'sass/partials',
    src: ['**/*.scss'],
    dest: 'styleguide/'
  }
}
```

I'm using grunt connect also and it fires up the pages fine. But for some reason it's not creating the iframe of HTML that it should be.

The .scss file has the correct markdown and (S)CSS in place -

```
/*

Alerts
======

Creates an alert box notification using the `.alert-` prefix. The following options are available:

    <p class="alert-success">Winning</p>
    <p class="alert-warning">Steady</p>
    <p class="alert-error">Oh Shit!</p>

*/

@mixin alert($colour){
  color: darken($colour, 50%);
  background: $colour;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.alert-success { @include alert(#e2f3c1) }
.alert-warning { @include alert(#fceabe) }
.alert-error   { @include alert(#ffdcdc) }
```

The handlebars file - https://github.com/sturobson/Squeeler/blob/master/source/styleguide.hbs -should be generating an iframe from the above. But it's not.

I did have this working, and I'm unsure what I've done to break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sassdown developer here. This was caused by Sassdown not registering Markdown code blocks indented with tabs rather than spaces. Have [just fixed this](https://github.com/nopr/sassdown/issues/11) in the latest build (0.0.9). Cloned your repository to test and updated the dependency version in your Gruntfile. IFRAME loaded fine. Good luck!